# memory with different speeds

Tags: memory

What would be better?

Having all 4 of these in my rig:

`DDR2 SDRAM DDR2 667 (PC2 5300) 2x @2gb each` and `DDR2 SDRAM DDR2 800 (PC2 6400) 2x @2gb each`

Or just the:

`DDR2 SDRAM DDR2 800 (PC2 6400) 2x @2gb each` since they have a higher speed?

Comment: More RAM is better. The speed difference is almost negligible. I'd go with the faster ones in the first slots, but depending on the motherboard, they'll probably all clock down to match the slower speed anyway.

Comment: More RAM is better if you're using it all. If not then faster RAM is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Motherboards usually adapt to the lower speed. Since you have 4GB of higher speed RAM I suggest installing only higher speed ones. If you need more than 4GB which is unlikely then you have no option. Extra memory won't increase speed unless you need it (then it's not extra)! So if your computer usually needs less than 2GB then 4GB is more than enough.